# Change menu item color using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to change the color of my menu items on-click. This was working fine but somehow I broke it and cant figure out how.

The menu item color is not changing when clicked. There are no errors.

I'm testing on Chrome. It is not working in production nor on localhost.

I think I must be missing a jQuery script somewhere...Any ideas are appreciated...

**Header:**

```
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" />
```

**Body:**

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item" onclick="changeactive('Home')">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">@_loc[Model.NavBarHome]</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" onclick="changeactive('Features')">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Features" asp-action="Features">@_loc[Model.NavBarFeatures]</a>
                </li>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.normal-item {
    color: green !important;
}
.active-item {
    color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.781) !important
}
```

**JS:**

```
function changeactive(pname) {

    Debug.writeln("hello");

    sessionStorage.setItem("activepage", pname);
}

$(function () {
    var pname = sessionStorage.getItem("activepage");

    switch (String(pname)) {
        case "Home":
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("active-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("normal-item");
            break;
        case "Features":
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("normal-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("active-item");
            break;
        default:
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("normal-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("normal-item");
            break;
    }

})
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly doesn't work. What errors do you encounter and what functionality is missing?

Comment: The menu item color is not changing when clicked. There are no errors. Question amended.

Comment: I don't see anything calling your anonymous function, maybe make that function the called function?

Comment: Well, you're `onclick` listener calls the `changeactive` function. But that only updates the session storage key. Is the other function supposed to run when navigation has occured?

Comment: There is '[snip]' in header section, if it is unnecessary  then you may consider to remove. To apply color on clicked menu item, you can give id or class and then add CSS property. This could be alternate and it will better rather than traversing all the DOM and then applying the CSS property.

Comment: Consider using your backend to set an active class based on the page that it is currently on.

Comment: Danimal - I tried making my bound function the called function, this did not work. Emiel - Yes the 2nd function is bound and executes when the DOM has finished loading. Can you point me in the direction of a tutorial on setting the active class based on a page identifier please? Prabhat - The [snip] is to indicate I removed some code from my header in the example. I have amended my question.

Answer (score 0):

1) The first time you run this code, pname will be undefined or empty.

2) you have an onclick handler, but the main logic of your code is not a function, so it will only run one time - and you're not observing the change of the sessionStorage1s value at all.

3) refactor your code to have the change logic in a function, and call that function in the changeactive fn too.

```
$(function () {

function updateUI()
{

    var pname = sessionStorage.getItem("activepage");

    switch (String(pname)) {
        case "Home":
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("active-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("normal-item");
            break;
        case "Features":
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("normal-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("active-item");
            break;
        default:
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").addClass("normal-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").addClass("normal-item");
            break;
    }
}

function changeactive(pname) {

    Debug.writeln("hello");

    sessionStorage.setItem("activepage", pname);
    updateUI();
}


});
```

Comment: I'm getting a function 'changeactive' is declared but its value is never read message

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-pname="Home" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home"
          asp-action="Index">@_loc[Model.NavBarHome]</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-pname="Features" asp-area="" asp-controller="Features"
          asp-action="Features">@_loc[Model.NavBarFeatures]</a>
      </li>
  </div>
```

```js
$(function () {
      var navBar = $('.navbar-nav');
      navBar.on('click', function (e) {
        var pname = e.target.dataset['pname'];
        changeactive(pname);
      })
      function changeactive(pname) {
        switch (String(pname)) {
          case "Home":
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").removeClass('normal-item').addClass("active-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").removeClass('active-item').addClass("normal-item");
            break;
          case "Features":
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").removeClass('active-item').addClass("normal-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").removeClass('normal-item').addClass("active-item");
            break;
          default:
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(1) a").removeClass('active-item').addClass("normal-item");
            $("ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item:nth-child(2) a").removeClass('active-item').addClass("normal-item");
            break;
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: The `changeactive` function is scoped within the jQuery IIFE, so it won't be available to the event listener.

Comment: yes, I try it in my mac...
and update the answer, maybe it is useful for u

Comment: This is still not working. I'm still wondering if there is an issue with my jQuery scripts because it was all working previously...

Answer (score 0):

If you use addClass, the new class is added on top of the existing ones already applied to the element. So you might end up with "normal-item" and "active-item" on the same element. This might be causing the unexpected behaviour.

Suggest you use .css({class:"nav-link normal-item"}) or .css({class:"nav-link active-item"}) to make sure only one the applicable classes are added.